# If/else statement with sum aggregation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I need to make segmentation of clients using condition statements.
This is sample table

| ID | Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-01 | 50 |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 50 |
| 2 | 2023-04-01 | 20 |
| 2 | 2023-05-01 | 20 |

I need following output, where VIP client paid more than 50 per month and more than 80 during all period and Middle client is else

| ID | Date | Revenue | Segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-01 | 50 | VIP |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 50 | VIP |
| 2 | 2023-04-01 | 20 | Middle |
| 2 | 2023-05-01 | 20 | Middle |

I have tried to make if else statement, but it works only for one month payment, not for the aggregated sum for all the period:

```
def f(segment):
    if segment['Revenue']>= 50:
        val = 'VIP'
    else:
        val = 'Middle'
    return val

df['Segment'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

How can I add condition `df.groupby('ID')['Revenue'].sum() > 80` in here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a step by step process of what I think you want to do :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([("1","2023-04-01",50), ("1","2023-05-01",50), 
                         ("2","2023-04-01",20), ("2","2023-04-01",20)],
                  columns=["ID", "Date", "Revenue"])

more_than_100_df = df.groupby("ID").sum("Revenue")
more_than_100_df = more_than_100_df.reset_index()
more_than_100_df["flag_vip"] = np.where(more_than_100_df['Revenue']>=80, 1, 0)

more_than_50_monthly_set = set(df[df["Revenue"] >= 50].ID)

VIP_IDs = set(more_than_100_df[(more_than_100_df["flag_vip"] == 1) & (more_than_100_df["ID"].isin(more_than_50_monthly_set))].ID)

df["Segment"] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(VIP_IDs), "VIP", "Middle")
```

---

editing after the requests in the comment:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([("1","2023-04-01",50), ("1","2023-05-01",50), 
                   ("2","2023-04-01",20), ("2","2023-04-01",20),
                   ("3","2023-04-01",30), ("3","2023-04-01",20)],
                  columns=["ID", "Date", "Revenue"])

def more_than_tot(df: DataFrame, value: float) -> set:
       more_than_value = df.groupby("ID").sum("Revenue").reset_index()
       more_than_value = more_than_value[more_than_value['Revenue']>=value].ID
       return set(more_than_value)

vip_more_than_tot = more_than_tot(df=df, value=80)
pre_vip_more_than_tot = more_than_tot(df=df, value=50)

def more_than_monthly(df: DataFrame, value_more: float, value_less: float) -> set:
       if value_more:
              df = df[df["Revenue"] >= value_more]
       if value_less:
              df = df[df["Revenue"] < value_less]
       if not value_less and not value_more:
              raise Exception("please add at least a value")
       return set(df.ID)
       
vip_monthly_set = more_than_monthly(df=df, value_more=50, value_less=None)
pre_vip_monthly_set = more_than_monthly(df=df, value_more=10, value_less=50)

VIP_IDs = vip_more_than_tot.intersection(vip_monthly_set) 
pre_VIP_IDs = pre_vip_more_than_tot.intersection(pre_vip_monthly_set)

df["Segment"] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(VIP_IDs), "VIP", 
                         np.where(df['ID'].isin(pre_VIP_IDs), "pre_VIP", "Middle"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me! But also got a question, how to change this code, if I have one more condition, for example: VIP > 50 per month and > 80 during all period , then pre_VIP > 20 per month and < 10 and > 50 for all the period  , else is Middle

Comment: i'll change the code accordingly, if the answer helps please upvote and accepts it

Comment: I've made the requested changes and I've added a "pre_vip" row :)

Comment: This looks like a very complicated approach… [you can solve this in two or line lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000892/16343464)

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop, use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Segment'] = np.where(df.groupby('ID')['Revenue'].transform('sum') > 50,
                         'VIP', 'Middle')
```

Output:

```
   ID        Date  Revenue Segment
0   1  2023-04-01       50     VIP
1   1  2023-05-01       50     VIP
2   2  2023-04-01       20  Middle
3   2  2023-05-01       20  Middle
```

If you have multiple categories, use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['Segment'] = pd.cut(df.groupby('ID')['Revenue'].transform('sum'),
                       bins=[0, 50, 80, 100],
                       labels=['Middle', 'pre_VIP', 'VIP'])
```

Example:

```
   ID        Date  Revenue  Segment
0   1  2023-04-01       50      VIP
1   1  2023-05-01       50      VIP
2   2  2023-04-01       20   Middle
3   2  2023-05-01       20   Middle
4   3  2023-04-01       15  pre_VIP
5   3  2023-05-01       40  pre_VIP
```